# Are these sentences with "as" equivalent?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I wrote:

> As I checked "Pied" in French, it means "foot", which is "Pā" in Persian.

I am not sure what my sentence means. Is it equivalent to the following sentences that are my purpose in the sentence above:

> According to what I read about "Pied" in French, it means "foot", which is "Pā" in Persian.
>
> From what I read about "Pied" in French, it means "foot", which is "Pā" in Persian.
>
> Based on what I read about "Pied" in French, it means "foot", which is "Pā" in Persian.

Comment: I don’t know for sure, but the other 3 options look a lot better than that first one. I wouldn’t use *as* that way.

Comment: **as** is not an idiomatic choice in your scenario. You might say *As I have checked **pied** in a good French dictionary, I am certain that it means "foot".*  In that case **as** would by synonymous with **since**.  But you could not say "Since I checked *pied* in a good dictionary, it means "foot". That it means "foot" is not itself the result of your having checked.

Comment: It is unclear why you want to write the sentence in that way. **The French word "Pied" means "Foot", which in Persian is "Pā".**

Comment: @weather what is a sentence including "check" or "looked up" and "according to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common meanings of "as" when used as the first word in a sentence include **in the same way**, **at the same time**, and **because**. That is, you might say

> As (i.e., in the same way that) I checked those words in French, so would I use various other translation dictionaries that afternoon to check the rest of the words on my list.
>
> As (i.e., at the same time that) I checked "pied" in French, my friend across the library checked "fuß" in German.
>
> As (i.e., because) I had checked "pied" in French, my friend asked the next day whether the other words might have meaning in another language.

None of these makes sense in your first sentence because there is no implied comparison and because the meaning of the word is (essentially) timeless, without any action needed on your part.

Your other three sentences sound fine, are nearly equivalent in meaning and formality, and could be interchanged.

Comment: The first sentence is not so  idiomatic.

Comment: I agree; it would more natural to say, "I checked the other words on my list *as* I had checked 'pied' in the French translation dictionary." Or maybe it's the emphasis on the manner of the action that sounds unusual—there aren't very many ways to look up a word in a dictionary. Some examples selected by Meriam-Webster for the same definition are "As it happens, I know his brother." and "As is the case with many men, he seemed to be having a midlife crisis."